# Empty space below content using Parallax scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm using Parallax scrolling for my new site but I have found there's loads of empty space after the content has been scrolled past. It scrolls past the bottom of the content and there's nothing there.

I assume this is because the script is speeding up scrolling, since when I remove the Parallax effect the content stops at the bottom of the browser window like its supposed to.

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    /* Scroll event handler */
    $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
        parallaxScroll();
    });
});

/* Scroll the background layers */
function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#Body_Background').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.3))+'px');
    $('#Home_WelcomeMessage').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.305))+'px');
    $('#Home_ContentBox2').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.605))+'px');
    $('#Home_ContentBox3').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.995))+'px');
}
```

CSS:

```
#Body_Background { z-index: 3; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#Body_Wrapper { position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#Home_ContentBox1 { z-index: 5; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 950px; left: 0px; margin-top: 800px; padding: 0px; }
#Home_WelcomeMessage { z-index: 4; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 400px; top: 0; margin-top: 400px; }
#Home_ContentBox2 { z-index: 5; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 800px; left: 0px; margin-top: 100px; padding: 0px; }
#Home_ContentBox3 { z-index: 5; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 1000px; left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;  padding: 0px; }
```

Any help is most appreciated :)

Comment: deliver code would be great here, thank.

Comment: Sorry? Don't understand?

Comment: create some jsfiddle or codepen for us to help you about your problem.

Comment: You can see the site here: http://twobytwovideo.co.uk/new If you scroll down to the bottom it continues to scroll past the bottom of the content.

Comment: If I'm right because I checked it in chrome(works great) and in Firefox only got problem. Try to change $(window).scrollTop(); for $(document).scrollTop(); IE and FF got problem with that

Comment: Didn't work. It doesn't work properly for me in Firefox, Chrome or Safari. The content is supposed to stop after the blog section with white/grey background...

Comment: I'll look into that a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this.

For those who have the same problem in the future. I set the ContentBox1, 2 and 3 divs to absolute positioning instead of relative, and then pushed them down using margin-top to ensure they were in the correct position.